# Itext 7 - Undesired bottom margin when text is placed a in paragraph

Tags: java, margins, paragraph, itext7

I am using iText 7 and **placing paragraphs into a div**, I have set the `setMultipliedLeading(1.0F)` value but I get a **margin underneath the paragraphs that I do not want**. The **paragraphs in question** are the red ones labelled Para 1 and Para 2, the other paragraphs have divs to create additional space (as well exhibiting the same bottom margin issue) but I would still like to remove the extra bit of space I do not want for these as well (as demonstrated by the red paragraphs).

It looks like older versions of iText supported a spacing before and after a paragraph. Is there a way to achieve this with iText 7?

I have attached an image that shows this extra spacing, what you can see is just paragraphs with their background colour set. I want to remove the bottom margin and have the coloured sections sit flush with each other.

[image]

I have tried setting the bottom margin of the **paragraphs** like this `label.setMarginBottom(0.0F);` (label is a `Paragraph`) but the margin is still present.

Comment: Show us some more code. All of those dimensions can be changed using the proper parameters. It appears that you're not setting the right properties (but we'd need to see your code). The leading is the space between the lines *inside* a paramter. What is `label`? Is it a `Div` or a `Paragraph`? Don't make us guess. Are you aware of the `setMarginTop()` method?

Comment: I assumed (probably wrongly) that it was bottom margins, but I think that might be the correct answer. I will update with some code asap, I am not setting the margin top at all and I think that might also be added.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie removing the top margin as well as the bottom margin has given me the effect I am looking for. Perhaps I should delete this question thread?

Comment: `label` is a `Paragraph` (as are all of the coloured labels in the image), which is contained inside a div Perhaps I should delete this question thread? I have updated the question and highlighted parts to make it easier to read, it was not my intention to make anyone guess, I had thought it was clear enough from the question, hopefully now it is.

Comment: You can (1.) delete the question, or (2.) answer your own question by explaining how you solved the problem. I think (2.) is preferred on Stack Overflow because other people with the same problem can be helped by your answer. Note that you can accept your own answer after a short waiting period.

Comment: OK well I guess option 2 is preferable as someone else might end up looking for the same thing

Comment: OK, upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 4):

With thanks to Bruno for pointing me in the right direction, it seems that when you add text to a paragraph in iText7 it will automatically add a top and bottom margin.

This is very easy to remove:

```
private Paragraph createFieldLabel(final String text)
{
    final Paragraph label = new Paragraph(text);        
    label.setMultipliedLeading(1.0F);
    label.setFontSize(12.0F);
    label.setMarginBottom(0.0F);
    label.setMarginTop(0.0F);

    return label;
}
```